# carry on one's work vs. carry one's work on

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> He carried on his work. vs. He carried his work on.

Is there any difference between the two sentences?

I see the first one 'He carried on his work.' more often.

Comment: Interesting find! "He carried on his work" is correct. I can't find a single example of "carried his work on" where "on" isn't a preposition, like "*...carried his work on the Malay Peninsula up to the present*". I can't think of a grammatical reason why though. If "carry on" in this sense is a separable phrasal verb, "*carried his work on*" should be correct, but it's not. If it's a non-separable phrasal verb, then "*carried on it*" should be correct, but it's not. Very puzzling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepositions can be placed differently, often without any change in meaning.

For example:

- **Pull up** your pants.
- **Pull** your pants **up**.

'Carry on' is a phrasal verb. Notice how it is listed in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/carry-on):

> **carry (something) on**
> to continue doing something, or to cause something to continue

Even the listing shows that you can put the object (something) between the verb and the preposition, and it isn't uncommon:

- He **carried on** doing it for years.
- he **carried** it **on** for years.

From a purely grammatical point of view, there's nothing wrong with either of your examples.

However, 'carry on' is definitely more idiomatic. One reason why a particular phrasing becomes more idiomatic than another is to avoid ambiguity, and that certainly seems the case with this phrase. Separately, the two words have other meanings. For example:

> He **carried** his bags **on** to the plane.

This has nothing to do with '*carrying on*' in the sense of 'continuing', so we would **not** say "*he carried on his bags to the plane*". It makes sense to keep the phrase together when you are using it in the sense of continuing something.